# invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " ") with for loop

Tags: bash, scripting, scripting-language

Following script

```
read n
for (( c=1; c<=$n; c++ ))
do
    echo "HI"
done
```

gives error `solution.sh: line 2: ((: c<=1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")`

I am using BASH. What is wrong with the `for` loop?

edit:
I am working on the BASH [hackerrank IDE](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lonely-integer-2/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) and although this code is not directly related to the problem in this link, I am getting this error.

Comment: Did you add `#!/bin/bash` top line?

Comment: Tested this in GIT Bash installed in Windows 10 along with `gnuwin32`. Works flawlessly. I would also suggest verifying if `#!/bin/bash` is present at the top of the bash script.

Comment: Can you `cat -v solution.sh` and make sure there are no funny characters in it?

Comment: I am getting this error on the [hackerrank IDE](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lonely-integer-2/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) but it is good to know that the loop is alright. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced this error message by pressing Ctrl-E after 1. It looked like this:

```
$ ./1.sh 
1^E
./1.sh: line 3: ((: c<=1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "")
```

So make sure you are not pressing some strange combination of keys before enter.

Comment: Could this be an internal error on the [Hackerrank IDE](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lonely-integer-2/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) ? I am getting the error there. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top of `solution.sh`.

(if your *bash* is at a different location, do, in a terminal,

```
which bash
```

to determine its location)

Answer (score 0):

@picasso13 just a wild guess cause it got me(and yield the same mysterious error when I tried to loop with array constructed from the input). There are 2 inputs on hackerRank(the first one is actually the size of the second). It solved my problem when I threw away the first and make sure my iteration was working on the list of numbers:

```
freq=()
for i in {1..100}; do
    freq[$i]=0
done    
read ignore
read inputs
IFS=', ' eval 'array=($inputs)'


for i in "${array[@]}"; do 
    (( freq[$i]++ )) 
done
for i in "${!freq[@]}"; do
    if [[ freq[$i] -eq 1 ]]; then
        echo $i
    fi
done
```

if you comment out my `read ignore` you'll reproduce the issue.